# Deletion of object and its children using Entity Framework 6 in ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been getting an exception when trying to delete an object using EF:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' >occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

The inner exception states:

> InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException
>
> ```
>   HResult=-2146233087
>   Message=A relationship from the 'PostableABC_Comments' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'PostableABC_Comments_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.
> ```

These are my Models:

```
public abstract class PostableABC
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : PostableABC
{
    [Required]
    public virtual PostableABC ParentPost { get; set; }
}

public class BlogPost : PostableABC
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following in my DbContext:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<PostableABC> Posts { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PostableABC>()
       .HasMany(x => x.Comments)
       .WithRequired(x => (PostableABC)x.ParentPost)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Here is the relevant code, marked with the location of the exception being thrown.

In BlogPostManager class:

```
    internal void DeleteBlogPost(int BlogPostId)
    {
        BlogPost DomainBlogPost = (BlogPost)db.Posts.Include("Author").Include("Comments").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == BlogPostId);

        CommentManager cm = new CommentManager();

        foreach (Comment c in db.Posts.OfType<Comment>().Where(x => x.ParentPost.Id == BlogPostId).ToList())
        {
            cm.DeleteComment(c.Id);
        }

        db.Posts.Remove(DomainBlogPost);
        db.SaveChanges(); // EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
    }
```

In CommentManager class:

```
    internal void DeleteComment(int CommentId)
    {
        Comment DomainComment = (Comment) db.Posts.Include("Author").Include("Comments").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == CommentId);

        foreach(Comment c in DomainComment.Comments.ToList())
        {
            DeleteComment(c.Id);
        }

        db.Posts.Remove(DomainComment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I can delete a BlogPost that has no Comments, and I can delete a Comment, however when I try to delete a BlogPost that has a Comment I get the exception.

I have been searching for hours and cannot find a solution to this problem. I would appreciate any help in resolving this, as well as any other suggestions you might have. Thank you.

---

UPDATE

I tried changing my Comment class

```
public class Comment : PostableABC
{   
    [Key, ForeignKey("ParentPost")]
    public virtual int ParentPostId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual PostableABC ParentPost { get; set; }
}
```

But now when I get to db.SaveChanges() when deleting the BlogPost I get a DbEntityValidationException saying "The ParentPost field is required."

Comment: What's your inner exception? It seems clear from the error message that it contains more useful details.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around for a while I finally managed to get it working properly, though I do not completely understand the logic behind it.

First thing I did was get rid of the `DbSet<PostableABC>` and introduced `DbSet<BlogPost>` and `DbSet<Comment>`.

After that I got rid of the ParentPostId in the Comment class. I also took out any foreign keys, and leaving the only key (primary key) as the Id in PostableABC. As well, I got rid of the OnModelCreating method in the DbContext.

And finally, the strange thing that got everything working properly was doing the delete on the parent object before doing it on child objects. Logically I don't think this makes any sense, however with entity framework, it seems to be the only way to do this (at least it it is for this situation).

If anyone has anything to say about this or elaborate you are more than welcome, I just hope that this can assist someone in the trouble they might come across.